# Extrema of the set of values $|f(-1/2)|$ for analytic functions $f \colon \mathbb{D} \to \mathbb{D}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a past qual question here: consider the set $S = \{ |f(-1/2)| \colon \textrm{$f \colon \mathbb{D} \to \mathbb{D}$ is analytic and has a triple zero at the origin} \}$, where here $\mathbb{D}$ denotes the unit disk. Find the infimum and supremum of $S$, if they exist.

Any help or hints are much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information we have about $f$ could be expressed as: $f(z)=z^3 g(z)$ where $g(0)\ne 0$ and $|g|\le 1$ in $\mathbb D$.

Clearly, the modulus of $f(-1/2)$ is directly related to the modulus of $g(-1/2)$.

- We can make $|g(-1/2)|$ small... yes, very small -- how about zero? Think of a function that has $(z+1/2)$ in it, and is bounded by $1$.
- We can make $|g(-1/2)|$ large... but no more than $1$ of course. Can $1$ be attained? Sure.